# Meaning of "entertain" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> Hearers will accept what speakers say, and so speakers will reasonably
> expect hearers to accept, consider, or **entertain** what they say
> about objects or states of affairs not within the immediate perceptual
> vicinity of the interlocutors.
>
> — The Reliability of Testimony, Peter J. Graham,
> *Philosophy and Phenomenological Research* via [JStor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2653619)

What is the meaning of *entertain* in the above sentence. The only meanings of the word that I could find ([Dictionary.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/entertain)) and are relevant here are *to receive* and *to consider*. But those meanings are already there via words *accept* and *consider*. Is there any other sense that can be relevant here, and cannot be taken to be already given via words *accept* and *consider*?

Comment: "consider" is good. To "entertain" means to listen, understand, think about, but not necessarily accept or reject.

Comment: On the one hand, the series "accept, consider, or entertain" can be understood as indicating a progressively weakening range of responses to a thesis—from acceptance of the thesis to weighing the merits of the thesis to merely receiving the thesis for possible consideration. On the other hand, the author may simply have engaged in overwriting—offering "entertain" as an alternative to "consider" in a situation where it really provides no greater insight or value than the writer would have achieved without including the third term. Such things do happen, even in  academic papers.

Comment: Please show evidence of research (this means showing what various online dictionaries say). I think that CED lists a (sub-) sense other than 'give full acceptance to' and 'at least consider as possibly true/profitable'. // The trouble with polysemy-with-hypernymy is that things get unwieldy and confusing when such words are used together. With the subsenses 'entertain' is allowed,  this could logically (but not acceptably) be rendered 'speakers will reasonably expect hearers to entertain(a), entertain(b) or entertain(c) what they say'.

Answer (score 2):

Here, ***entertain*** means

> to keep, hold, or maintain in the mind
>
> - I ***entertain*** grave doubts about her sincerity.
>
> to receive and take into consideration
>
> - refused to ***entertain*** our plea ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entertain))

*Entertain* may be considered redundant in your sentence, but it may be the author's stylistic choice to emphasise a fact by expressing it in different words that overlap in meaning. Note that *accept*, *consider* and *entertain* are connected by ***[or](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/or)***, which can mean ***in other words***.

Answer (score -1):

The word **entertain** when used that manner is often shaded with the sense of being *willing to consider* or "open" to something.

Merriam-Webster defines it as "*to receive* and take into consideration" [my emphasis]

and Cambridge defines it as "to hold in your mind or to *be willing to consider* or accept:" [my emphasis]

So the author is setting up a continuum, with acceptance at one end and open to considering at the other:

accepting ... considering ... willing to consider

> They refuse even to entertain the notion that their leader is a con-man.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, since there was no explanation offered.

Answer (score -2):

To entertain in this sentence means to accept something without knowing the truth and think about it and its consequences.. a good example would be...""A good phillosopher would  entertain the imaginary situations "

Comment: The OP already knows, in general terms, what *entertain* means. The question is specifically whether its meaning differs from that of *consider*.